# The Support of Differential Forms defined by Pulling-Back on Complex Manifolds of the Same Dimension

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms, smooth-functions, complex-manifolds, pullback

Let $M,N$ be two complex manifolds of the same (complex) dimension.

Let $\omega$ be a differential form on the manifold $N$ whose support denoted by $S$.

Let $f: M \longrightarrow N$ be a smooth map.

How to define the support of the form $f^* \omega$ in terms of the support of $\omega$?

Comment: @Oiler this set is contained in the manifold $N$ the support of $f^* \omega$ is contained in $M$.

Comment: It is exactly $f^{-1}(\mathrm{supp} \omega)$: Just follow the definition of pull-back.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan The support is contained in $f^{-1}(\mathrm{supp}\omega)$ but they are not necessarily equal. If $f:M\to N$ is the map $f(m)=n_0$ for all $m\in M$ then $T_mf=0$ for all $m$. This means that for each $\omega\in \Omega^n(N)$, $f^*\omega=0$ and $\mathrm{supp} f^*\omega=\varnothing$.